# Bootstrap 3 navigation too long to view on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

The navigation consists of 12 links (1 being a dropdown that has an additional 4) on a single page website. The problem arises on mobile devices. The whole navigation can be seen, however, selecting the dropdown menu only the first two links can be seen on larger screens and nothing can be seen on iphone 5 (as shown in pic below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nftb7.png)

If any of you guys have had similar issues or can offer a solution it would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: usually the screen should have a scroll bar if the menu overflows

Comment: Can you post your code? It should work fine: http://www.bootply.com/NrOYpKMcDe

Comment: I do remember there being a scrollbar but I got rid of it as it was so ugly. Of course now I cant remember the markup. Shot myself in the foot there! Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is the jsfiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/1gu7tmgw/

Comment: This is what tripped me up: navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 800px;
}